# there is an unknown character in /var/lib/containers

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I try to gather containers' logs that kubernetes produced and in /var/lib/containers the logs are as follow

```
2023-04-09T10:54:20.639820293+03:30 stdout F <service log>
```

I don't know what is that F character after stdout does anybody know about that character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the `tags` field of the log line. Taken from the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/node/kubelet-cri-logging.md#proposed-solution)

> The tags fields can support multiple tags, delimited by :. Currently, only one tag is defined in CRI to support multi-line log entries: partial or full. Partial (P) is used when a log entry is split into multiple lines by the runtime, and the entry has not ended yet. Full (F) indicates that the log entry is completed -- it is either a single-line entry, or this is the last line of the multiple-line entry.

Hence, the `F` stands for full-line, where `P` stands for partial (multiline log event)